# Scanned Input in python as a single Input

Tags: python, input, raspberry-pi, evdev

I have written this code where I process scanned input from barcode scanner. But input here are from single line and I can't get difference between the next scanned input and the past one. Here is my code:

```
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes
import select

dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event2')
data = ""

def parse_key_to_char(val):
    return CODE_MAP_CHAR[val] if val in CODE_MAP_CHAR else ""

for event in dev.read_loop():
    if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
        e = categorize(event)
        if e.keystate == e.key_up:
            print parse_key_to_char(e.keycode)
```

And the Output is:

```
0
7
5
6
7
8
1
6
4
1
2
5
```

While expected output is :

```
075678164125
```

It works if I am in the same terminal but won't work if I am focusing on some other terminal. I want these inputs to be captured in the background and pass them to some other function which is calling current function.

Comment: Seems like the problem may lie within your `parse_key_to_char()` function.

Comment: def parse_key_to_char(val):
    return CODE_MAP_CHAR[val] if val in CODE_MAP_CHAR else ""

Comment: Don't post code in comments, edit/add it to your post if it is relevant

Comment: It was edited but I mistakenly add code in the comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space) Assuming you're in Python 2, I *highly* recommend the `__future__` import and using the new version. Future proofs your code *and* is a cleaner, more intuitive solution.

Comment: Also, I think you mean **"output"** in most of the places where you say "input" in this question.

Answer (score 0):

`print` automatically adds a new line at the end of printed text. You need to add all symbols to one string and then print it:

```
for event in dev.read_loop():
    if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
        e = categorize(event)
        if e.keystate == e.key_up:
            text = text + parse_key_to_char(e.keycode)
print text
```

PS. You can add a comma after `print`, then there will be no new line, but a space:

```
for i in range (5):
    print i,
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: read_loop is an endless loop so it won't terminate to print outside for loop.

Comment: How do you determine when one input ends and the other begins?

Comment: Depending on the python version, `print` may need to be `print()` (Python 3)

Comment: @DavidOwens Yes, but posted code has no `()` so it's not Python 3 ;) And as far as I know, Python2 is the default version on RasPi.

Comment: @Psytho I am trying to figure out that. But since after specific input, there is a time gap I am writing a thread to clear variable and capture new variable

Comment: You can put single numbers in a string on the receiver side. And when after a certain time gap no further numbers come, that would mean the end of a barcode. If you use standardized barcode, they have BEGIN and END marks.

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/216712.

Comment: @jpmc26 And how exactly am I supposed to know it is a duplicate?

Comment: @Psytho Most problems are common and have already been asked and answered. Searching for duplicates before you answer is always a prudent step, doubly so if you recognize the problem quickly.